# Android studio button bring up black screen instead of code

Tags: java, android-studio, button

Please help, I can't figure out why it keeps taking me to black screen.

The `Study` button works fine, but the `start` button is being dumb.
`start` button is supposed to open a new activity but instead opens a black screen appears.

I have tried a bunch of stuff, it just doesn't work:

```
package com.example.rupin.whosthatpokemon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class questionactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questionactivity);
        Button start = findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), one.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        start = findViewById(R.id.study);
        start.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent i;
                        i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/"));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

    }
    public void goToActivity2 (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, one.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot set listeners to a single button. Try initialize both button start and study to separate buttons and set listeners.

you question seems not that clear. i hope this is the problem.

check below edited code.

```
package com.example.rupin.whosthatpokemon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class questionactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_questionactivity);
            Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
            start.setOnClickListener(
                .
                .
                .
                .
            );
            Button study =(Button) findViewById(R.id.study);
            study.setOnClickListener(
                .
                .
                .
                .
            );

        }
        public void goToActivity2 (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, one.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```